# Count Occurrences of Visible Text in HTML Document

Tags: php, html, domxpath

I am attempting to count the occurrences of a string within an HTML document returned by a curl request. I would normally do this with `substr_count`, but I am looking to match on only user-visible text (the text seen in a browser loaded page), not all matches in the source. As an example, encountering the following paragraph:

```
<p class="example">example</p>
```

Searching for the string "example", I would expect to count one occurrence here, since the class name should be omitted from the count. I am currently using DOMXpath to parse other portions of the HTML document, so I looked into using it for this purpose as well by using:

```
$xpath->query("//text()[contains(., 'example')]");
```

Which I found other people use to find text in the document, but this seems to also count findings within tags as well. Is there a way to count on just user-visible text? I want to note that user-visible just means the text is not part of meta data, attributes, and the likes. If a component is styled to not be seen, but would otherwise produce visible text, that text should be counted. For example:

```
<p class="example" style="visibility:hidden">example</p>
```

Should still count one occurrence as done before.

**EDIT**

`strip_tags` will handle the instances I have shown. Is there a way to handle instances found within scripts and the like? The following should not attribute to the count:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var example = 1 ....other stuff....</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to remove the tags.

```
$str = '<p class="example">example</p>
<p class="example" style="visibility:hidden">example</p>
<script type="text/javascript">var example = 1 
....other stuff....
</script>';

$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){

   if(strpos($arr[$i], "hidden") !== false){
       // remove hidden tag
       unset($arr[$i]);
   }else if(strpos($arr[$i], "<script") !== false){
        while(strpos($arr[$i], "</script") === false){
            // remove the scripts from the html. 
            unset($arr[$i]);
            $i++;
        }
        unset($arr[$i]); // and remove the last line with "</script"
   }
}
$str = implode(PHP_EOL, $arr);

Echo substr_count(strip_tags($str), "example");
```

https://3v4l.org/d4JN5

Comment: That would take care of inline occurrences, is there any way to handle occurrences within scripts? I'll edit the question to show better

Comment: @yanman1234 Point noted... Try the code above. It may not work perfectly but it's a proof of concept. Split the html on new line and look at each line for hidden or script and remove the line if found. Then all that is left should be tags and visible text, so a strip tags should give the correct result.

Comment: While this does have its pitfalls, I think you are right that I'll need to do a manual cleansing of the document before searching it. Thanks!

Comment: @yanman1234 Yes, as I said it's not perfect. But usually webpages have the same basic markup independent of it's content. So spending a few minutes looking at the markup and you should be able to tweek it to perfection.